# Is there a way to detect when code is pasted into an input?

Tags: jquery

using jQuery is there a way to capture the user's paste event and then determine if the user has pasted a code snippet? (ruby,php,html,css,js etc...)?

Thanks

Comment: What's your ultimate goal? Syntax highlighting?

Comment: @nickf correct, I'm interested in auto detecting code being pasted into a field and then showing the pasted code w Synatc highlighting.

Comment: Unless you really need quite specific language highlighting, one option is to use something like what Stack Overflow uses. The highlighting here doesn't assume any language at all, but just matches common patterns. It doesn't work so great when you paste in some SQL or something, but aside from that, it does a fairly competent job without requiring any analysis of the text.

Comment: @nickf you're saying to say anything with 4 spaces, consider code?

Comment: Ah, so your users might be pasting normal text as well as code? I though you wanted to detect the actual language of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Bind `paste` to your input.

Something like:

```
   $("selector").bind('paste', function(e) {
   //Get pasted text, need a small timeout
    var element = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
         var text = $(element).val();
         alert(text);
      }, 100);

   });
```

Comment: Thanks but I was asking how to detect if the user pasted code. And being able to wrap the code in a code tag or some other html tag to allow styling. Not just detecting the paste event.

Comment: To get pasted text you need a small timeout, i think it make sense to do what ever you are doing in this event handeler